# Increase web page speed and reduce request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any jQuery plugin or method for increasing my web page speed and reducing page size,decrease request as well?

Comment: http://minifycode.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Minify** your code. This will remove all the **unnecessary new lines**, **unreachable code snippets** etc. and make you resulting file smaller.

Then **split** your code into at least **2 main bundles** - library bundle and a custom code bundle. Since libraries don't change their code often this will result in more **efficient caching**.

**Evaluate your dependencies**. Sometimes we can get carried away with dependencies and we don't realize that we've imported a large amount of code that we're not using. Make sure you trim down to dependencies which you use more than ~50% (**this is trivial, adjust to context**) of their code.

Use of **CDN**'s will also increase response time because they aim at responding to resources according the where you are geographically.

Comment: @VaibhavTyagi did this help?

Answer (score 1):

There are online tools to **obfuscate** or **compress**.

-You can use **cdn** links of libraries that will probably download faster for client.

cdnjs for example : https://cdnjs.com/libraries/

-If you are using c# type language in your project there are **bundle configuration** that can decrease number of requests.

-There are also **resourceBundle** libraries for other languages like php etc..

A javascript/css **compression** tool that may work for you : http://compressor.atomproject.net/